# py2app tkinter application built on El capitan not working on a sierra

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, py2app

I built a py2app and Tkinter based application, and sent it to a friend, it does not seem to be working on the friends laptop that runs OSX sierra. Is there anything I can do?

When I try to open the application on my friends computer it just says Hook Error (name of the application is hook).

Comment: I definatly suggest you build with `$ python setup.py py2app -A` then run it, this will show you errors in a terminal, once you fix the errors build as `$ python setup.py py2app`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hey @halfer thanks for the info, will keep this in mind going forward. Noob mistake. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

So if some one else is facing the same issue, the best way to figure out what is wrong is to run the console version of the app by going to the MacOS folder. In this specific case, sierra was not letting my app create a log file, siting lack of permissions, which was wierd, it seems like sierra has some extra security feature that doesnt let 3rd party apps create new files (just a guess, could be some other reason too), so when I opened the app from terminal with 'sudo', the problem was fixed. I had to do this only once though, even after restarts double clicking the icon opened up the application and updated the log file too. Hope this helps if you came in search of answers here.